# How can I redirect a single port in a docker container to the container's host?

Tags: docker, iptables

To make development easier for a project, I've put a couple of services it depends on in docker containers.  This makes 'localhost' in the project's config mean something different when it is passed to one of the containers.

*edit*

To be clear, I'm trying to forward one of the **container's** ports **to the host** so when a process running in the container tries to access localhost:5432, it connects to the **host's** port 5432.

*endedit*

I'm currently using

```
HOST_IP=`ip route | grep default | awk '{ printf "%s",$3 }'`
cat /etc/hosts | sed "s/127.0.0.1/$HOST_IP/" > /tmp/etc_hosts
cp /tmp/etc_hosts /etc/hosts
```

to redirect anything targeting 'localhost' to the container's host.  It works in this situation, but I'd prefer to find a way to do this only for the needed port as I expect it won't work in other situations.

Here's what I came up with to do that, but it's not working; when a connection in the container is to localhost:5432, it tries to connect to the container's 5432 instead of the host's:

```
# --- These are the things that should make redirecting port 5432 to the host machine
#     work, provided the container is run in privileged mode.
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to 172.19.0.1:5432
iptables -A FORWARD -d 172.19.0.1 -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Why won't you just use `-p` ?

Comment: @RandallFlagg, see edit.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand well, for development, you'd want *localhost* to resolve to a specific container, including when it's called from another container.

## Host forwarding

Rewriting your `hosts` file is, as you mentioned it, not a good idea, since many services can experiment issues if you design *localhost* as being something different than, well... your local host.

But you can consider a few solutions.

### Docker Toolbox

If running *docker* with `Docker Toolbox`, or by yourself on a virtual machine with `Virtual Box`, the intermediate virtual machine is visible, so `localhost` will represent it. You'll have to run the container, exposing this port, and then to set up a port forwarding in *Virtualbox*. If I use *Wordpress* as an example:

1. `docker run  -p 80:80 --name website -d wordpress`
2. Virtual Box -> your docker VM (usually called *default*) -> Network -> Adapter 1 -> port forwarding -> create a mapping from host 8080 to guest 80

It will make *Wordpress* available at `http://localhost:8080`. Please note that under *MacOS*, the kernel restrains non-privileged port forwarding (ports under 1024).

This port forwarding can be created in command line, if you want to put it in a script:
`VBoxManage modifyvm "default" --natpf1 "app,tcp,,8080,,80"`

### Docker for Windows/Docker for Mac

If running *docker* through `Docker for Windows`/`Docker for Mac` (or directly under `Linux`), rather than `Docker Toolbox`, you can run the container using the `-p` parameter, as specified by *Scott*'s post, and your service will be available on *localhost* at this port (because the intermediate virtual machine is transparent, or no VM under Linux):

`docker run -p 5432:5432 --name myapp -d myimage` will make *myapp* available at `localhost:5432`.

### socat (or iptables)

You can run **socat** on your *host* this way to forward communication on a specific port to your container:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:5432,fork,reuseaddr,user=node,group=node,mode=777 TCP:172.19.0.1:5432 &`

(where *172.19.0.1* is your container IP)

## Container forwarding

### --network

Your containers have their own `hosts` file, that you can see by issuing such a command:

`docker run ubuntu cat /etc/hosts`

You can add entries to `hosts` with the `--add-host` parameter:

`docker run --add-host domain:1.2.3.4 --add-host domain2:5.6.7.8 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts`

However this solution will be useless for `localhost`, because it won't remove the previous `localhost` associations. What you're looking for (and what is cleaner) is the parameter `--network=host` which allows the container to share the network interfaces of the host:

`docker run --network=host ubuntu`

This way, your container will be able to call the other containers services on localhost using their port.

### The right way

Of course, the right way to achieve what you want would be to link your containers together and use their link names rather than *localhost*.

```
docker run -d  --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mariadb 
docker run -d --name="wordpress" -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password --link mariadb:mysql wordpress
```

In this case, the *Wordpress* container will have a *mysql* entry in its `hosts` file, pointing to the *mariadb* container IP address. To see it, open a `bash` session in the *Wordpress* container and see by yourself.

```
docker exec -ti wordpress bash
#cat /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, but no.  Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Ah, your edit makes it clearer, and you're right. The `host=network` parameter I suggest would work to reach another container(or service on a port running on the Docker VM), but  not on the host... I thought it would work with *Docker for Mac*, but a test proved that it doesn't. This is discussed here: https://forums.docker.com/t/should-docker-run-net-host-work/14215/26
Someone suggests, if using a *VirtualBox* based solution like *Docker Toolbox*, to complete with a reverse tunnel like `ssh -t -R5432:localhost:5432 docker@$(docker-machine ip default)` to connect VM on this port.
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Show us how you are launching your container

port mapping can happen in your docker run command :  -p hostport:containerport

as in

```
docker run  -p 5432:5432 --name mycontainer -d myimage
```

Comment: I'm trying to do opposite of that, the equivalent of -p containerport:hostport